# C read from file and write reverse

Tags: c, linux

In C i want to read from file a number of symbols and for each 2 of them i want to write them reversed. For example if the input is: abcdef i want the output to be: badcfe.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

FILE *f,*g;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    if((f=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Open file error: %s\n",argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if((g=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT,O_RDWR))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Open file error: %s\n",argv[2]);
        fclose(f);          
        return 1;
    }

    int nr;
    char *buffer;
    buffer=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    char *bufferOut=buffer;

    while((nr=read(f,buffer,2*sizeof(char))>0)){
        bufferOut[1]=buffer[0];

        bufferOut[0]=buffer[1];
        if(write(g,bufferOut,2*sizeof(char))!=2*sizeof(char)){
            printf("Writing ERROR!");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    close(f);
    close(g);
    return 0;
}
```

After execution when i open g, the content is: aaccee

I am on linux.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: You only have one buffer (with two pointers to it). Both "buffer" and "bufferOut" points to the same memory.

Comment: `char *buffer; malloc(sizeof(char));` --> `char *buffer; malloc(2);` or better yet `char buffer[2];`

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is in these lines of code:

```
bufferOut[1]=buffer[0];

bufferOut[0]=buffer[1];
```

bufferOut and buffer are pointing to the same areas of memory, based on these lines here:

```
char *buffer;
buffer=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
char *bufferOut=buffer;
```

This is not performing the swap that you want. Since bufferOut and buffer are pointing to the same areas of memory, you are assigning bufferOut[0] and bufferOut[1] to the same value. Try storing the original contents of bufferOut[1] in a temporary variable and then assigning that into bufferOut[0].

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by aglasser, the problem is:

```
bufferOut[1]=buffer[0];
```

This line causes the original content of bufferOut[1] to be lost.  A successful exchange requires additional storage.  Perhaps the following would be helpful:

```
char ch = bufferOut[1];
bufferOut[1]=buffer[0];
bufferOut[0]=ch;
```